# Grails 3.3.8 : Unable to resolve ControllerUnitTest

Tags: grails

I am attempting to write some basic controller tests and am following the documentation https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html. My test currently is unable to find **ControllerUnitTest**. Is there a dependency that I am missing?

Here is my import

```
grails.testing.web.controllers.ControllerUnitTest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/mcroteaucontrollertest.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mcroteaucontrollertest/blob/master/src/test/groovy/mcroteaucontrollertest/DemoControllerSpec.groovy

```
package mcroteaucontrollertest

import grails.testing.web.controllers.ControllerUnitTest
import spock.lang.Specification

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED

class DemoControllerSpec extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<DemoController> {

    void "test GET request"() {
        when:
        controller.index()

        then:
        response.text == 'Success'
    }

    void "test POST request"() {
        when:
        request.method = 'POST'
        controller.index()

        then:
        response.status == METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.value()
    }
}
```

The `ControllerUnitTest` trait is provided by `grails-web-testing-support`.  Make sure you have something like `testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"` as shown at https://github.com/jeffbrown/mcroteaucontrollertest/blob/cf5f09b1c2efaba759f6513301d7b55fcb29979b/build.gradle#L56.

Comment: Thank you. The example app worked perfect. However when I implement in a project outside I get `"groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException"` on the line that reads `controller.*` * equals method name. Do you know what could be causing this? Any additional guidance would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Would it matter if I am using a mixin for the controller? Thank you.

Comment: It has to do with my use of a @Mixin for controllers. Im not sure how to work around. Any ideas on what I should do? I would like to cover controllers if possible.

Comment: Which mixing are you trying to use in conjunction with the `ControllerUnitTest` trait?

Comment: The project you link at https://github.com/opengreenfield/greenfield/tree/web-testing is a Grails 3.2.8 project but you are trying to use the Grails 3.3 testing framework.

Comment: Ok, thank you. What would you recommend? What do I need to do to make my project a 3.3 project? http://docs.grails.org/3.2.x/guide/upgrading.html#upgrading32x Theres probably more to it than adding the converters dependency thats no longer there. Where do I specify what version?  Thank you

Comment: "What would you recommend?" - I recommend you upgrade the project.  "Where do I specify what version?" - Specifying the version is only 1 part of the upgrade but the version number is specified in `gradle.properties` at the top of the project.  The pull request at https://github.com/opengreenfield/greenfield/pull/12 represents a starting point.